# Getting the tables joined using foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

Student table:

```
(student_id(PK),student_name,subject_enrolled(FK))
```

Teacher table:

```
(teacher_id(PK),teacher_name,subject_teaches(FK))
```

Subject table:

```
(subject_id(PK),subject_name)
```

**How can i put a proper JOIN TABLES query for this such that:**

```
Student_id,teacher_name- multiple names 
(resulted from same subject_enrolled and subject_teaches)
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I think you need to review your schema, you will face interesting issues if a student can take multiple subjects or a teacher can teach multiple subjects.  Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)

Comment: @ymas, Yes sir! that's exactly what I'm trying to make. Thank you sir for the notice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM students AS st
LEFT JOIN subjects AS su ON su.subject_id = st.subject_enrolled
LEFT JOIN teachers AS t ON su.subject_id = t.subject_teaches
```

Comment: Its polish equivalent for Christopher. [google translate](https://translate.google.pl/#pl/en/Krzysztof%20Duszczyk) use listen option

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Select students.student_id,GROUP_CONCAT(teachers.teacher_name)
FROM students
JOIN teachers ON teachers.subject_teaches = students.subject_enrolled
GROUP BY students.student_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0d4eb/7/0)

Comment: i'll try this. Thanks sir :)

Comment: Sir @noufalcep , how can i create a php script using this? An executing command? Thanks